# What is the difference between QFT and QED?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics

What is the difference between [QFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory) and [QED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_electrodynamics)?  In QFT electron is field quanta, what is electron in QED?

Comment: I thought QED is a type of QFT?

Answer (score 11):

The comment by Aaron Stevens is right: QED is a specialization of QFT.

QFT is a collection of general principles. It is a specialization of quantum theory (it respects all of the principles of quantum theory and includes some more), but it is still very broad. QED is a further specialization. QED is a relatively simple QFT in which the only dynamic entities are the electromagnetic field and one or more fermion fields (such as the electron field). In QED, electron *particles* are quanta of the electron *field*, as suggested in the question.

QCD (quantum chromodynamics) is a different specialization of QFT. The Standard Model of particle physics is another one. Other examples are abundant, most of them less relevant to the real world but still useful for building intuition. Here's a Venn diagram to illustrate the relationships:

[image]

By the way, the relationship between particles and fields is not always straightforward. For example, in QCD, the *fields* are quark and gluon fields, but the resulting *particles* are mesons (like pions) and baryons (like protons and neutrons). It is still correct to say that particles are field quanta, but not quanta of *individual fields*. Each particle in QCD is a collective phenomenon that involves all of the fields. The correspondence between fields and particles is more straightforward in QED, but it still involves some subtleties. One of the benefits of studying less-realistic-but-easier specializations of QFT is to help build intuition about such subtleties.

Comment: Why did Feynman say that the electron is a particle and not a field quanta?

Comment: @Philipsmett The intended meaning of the words isn't always clear, especially heavily overloaded words like "particle" and "quanta". Maybe Feynman was referring to what I called "subtleties." In models with no interactions (like QED with the electric charge set to zero), the field operators act like single-particle creation/annihilation operators, so "particles" and "field quanta" are interchangeable. But in most models (like QED with non-zero charge), the relationship between them is more subtle at best, and often very complicated. Maybe that's what Feynman meant.

Comment: @Philipsmett Or maybe Feynman was using "particle" to mean "localized" and "field quanta" to mean "quantum of energy" (which would be non-localized)... but I don't know. The words are not always used consistently, and I don't know how Feynman preferred to use them.

Comment: @Philipsmet The same reason why we still talk about EM waves or talk like there is absolute space and time. Even discussions of the standard model talk about fundamental particles. Just because there is more precise language doesn't mean it is always useful.